# Llenar combobox con dos columnas de una bd mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

mi consulta es más bien teorica, necesito que un ComboBox que toma valores de una bd de mysql, muestre dos campos de una tabla. Probé modificando la consulta, incluyendo un SELECT

```
SELECT campos, concat(campo1, ' ' ,campo2) as CAMPOFINAL from Tabla1
```

y en el `DisplayMember` del control poner `CAMPOFINAL` pero nada.

Si pudiesen darme una idea de como hacerlo, les agradecería.

Gracias.
Edito:

codigo para el combobox c# (no es web, es escritorio)

```
this.cmbDevUsuario.DataSource = new Solicitante().listaSolicitantes();
        this.cmbDevUsuario.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.cmbDevUsuario.ValueMember = "idUsuario";
        this.cmbDevUsuario.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
```

la lista del dataSource viene de acá (Clase Solicitante):

```
public List<Solicitante> listaSolicitantes()
    {
        solicitanteBD = new SolicitanteBD(this);
        return solicitanteBD.listaSolicitantes();
    }
```

la Clase de Acceso de Datos SolicitanteBD contiene:

```
public List<Solicitante> listaSolicitantes()
    {
        List<Solicitante> lista = new List<Solicitante>();


      String consulta = "SELECT idUsuario, concat(NombrePed, ' ', ApellidoPed) as NombreCompleto, Telefono from usuario";
        MySqlDataAdapter adaptador = new MySqlDataAdapter(consulta, this.cn);
        adaptador.Fill(this.tabla);


        foreach (DataRow fila in this.tabla.Rows)
        {
          Solicitante autFill = new Solicitante(fila[0].ToString(), fila[1].ToString(), fila[2].ToString());

            lista.Add(autFill);
        }

        return lista;
    }
```

Y cuando lo hago así, el comboBox no me muestra nada.

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo de como lo estas intentado en c#..para poder ayudarte

Comment: cuando dices que muestre estos dos campos de la tabla, necesitas que salga en la vista como un input u div?

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda en realidad la pregunta es.. estas trabajando web? wpf? winforms? no necesariamente es web ;).

Comment: Lo que estas haciendo del lado del sql es correcto. Podes mostrar un poco de tu codigo y tu pantalla para saber que paso...

Comment: falta saber si estas utilizando SqlDataAdapter o SqlDataReader para obtener los datos para ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @gbianchi en todo caso, leí combbox y me imaginé que era web.

Comment: @SebastiánMiranda hay combobox para escritorio tambien ;) es mas, el combobox viene del escritorio, y en web le cambiaron el nombre...

Comment: si pones un brekpoint en el codigo, puedes evaluar que al ejecutar la consulta se obtiene la infomacion de estos campos unidos? solo para conocer si es un problema de la consulta o la vinculacion con el combobox

Comment: new Solicitante().listaSolicitantes(); esta devolviendo una lista que tiene datos no?

Comment: @gbianchi si, la lista tiene datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aconsejaria uses el `reader` para llenar una lista

```
public List<Solicitante> listaSolicitantes()
{
    List<Solicitante> lista = new List<Solicitante>();

    string consulta = "SELECT idUsuario, concat(NombrePed, ' ', ApellidoPed) as NombreCompleto, Telefono from usuario";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(consulta, this.cn);

    var reader = cmd.ExecureReader();

    while(reader.Read())
    {
        Solicitante autFill = new Solicitante(reader["idUsuario"].ToString(), 
                                                reader["NombreCompleto"].ToString(), 
                                                reader["Telefono"].ToString());

        lista.Add(autFill);
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Ademas intentes poner las propiedades `DisplayMember` y `ValueMember` antes del `DataSource`

```
var dataAccess = new Solicitante();
var solicitantes = dataAccess.listaSolicitantes();

cmbDevUsuario.ValueMember = "idUsuario";
cmbDevUsuario.DisplayMember = "NombreCompleto";
cmbDevUsuario.DataSource = solicitantes;

cmbDevUsuario.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Debes tener una clase como ser

```
public class Solicitante
{
    public string idUsuario {get;set;}
    public string NombreCompleto {get;set;}
    public string Telefono {get;set;}
}
```

entonces cuando iteras podrias usar

```
while(reader.Read())
{
    Solicitante autFill = new Solicitante() 
                            {
                                idUsuario = reader["idUsuario"].ToString(), 
                                NombreCompleto = reader["NombreCompleto"].ToString(), 
                                Telefono = reader["Telefono"].ToString()
                            };

    lista.Add(autFill);
}
```

asi no necesitas ningun constructor

Comment: Hola, al usar el codigo que me facilitas, obtengo como respuesta del combo algo así como la ruta (por así decirlo): Libros.Negocios.Solicitante

Comment: ese es el namespace de la clase, no te esta tomando el `DisplayMember`. Estas definiendo propiedades en la clase `Solicitante ` ? o son variables publicas?

Comment: tengo creado lo siguiente:

private String idUsuario;
        private String nombrePed;
        private String apellidoPed;
        private String telefono;
        private SolicitanteBD solicitanteBD;

Además de los constructores y metodos set y get

Comment: agregue codigo mostrando como deberias definir la clase, los set/get no son metodos, esto no es java

Comment: Gracias, es la respuesta.